# Integrate smartcontract with reactjs

Tags: reactjs, solidity

I want to show data in reactjs application like public variables showing in remixid
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55jnk.png)

when I try to console it's showing
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PXOk.png)

```
    const contractBalance = aw ait contract.getBalance();
    const goal = await contract.goal();
    const admin = await contract.admin();
    const minCont = await contract.minimumContribution();
    const nOfCont = await contract.noOfContributors();
    const deadline = await contract.deadline();
    const numReq = await contract.numRequests();
    const raisedAmount = await contract.raisedAmount();
    const requestIndex = await contract.requests(0);

    console.log('data: ', ethers.utils.formatEther(contractBalance));
    console.log('requestIndex > ', requestIndex);
    console.log("minCont > " , minCont);
    console.log("numReq > " , numReq);
    console.log("raisedAmount > " , raisedAmount);
    console.log("nOfCont > " , nOfCont);
    console.log("admin > " , admin);
    console.log("deadline > " , deadline);
```

please help!
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because numbers in solidity are treated as BigNumbers.

The most simple way to convert them is by casting them to string:

```
console.log("minCont > " , minCont.toString());
```